# Can I add php code that will change list.phtml to display all products for the category?

Tags: magento

Can I add php code that will change list.phtml to display all products for the category?

Comment: Uh, doesn't it already list the products in the category?  I suppose if you have the products set to Disabled they won't show up, but I can't imagine you wanting to display disabled products.  Please clarify what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can do this:

```
$catid = "191";

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')  
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image', 'status'), 'inner')  
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid)); 
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

<div id="featured-products">
       <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
               <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
               <li><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'),null, true) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product,'small_image')->resize(75); ?>" width="75" height="75" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a></li>
               <?php endforeach ?>
       </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, it works, but you should avoid calling your model in a phtml file, specially in this case : if your block is a product/list, you'll have 2 product collections since one is already available from $thsi->getProductCollection() : you may have 2 MySQL calls...

Answer (score 0):

I'm recommed create new extension to display all product;

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mivec, you have to add you own code in a new Magento module.
You'll probably have to rewrite the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection() to change the default filter.